# Word wrap in JList items

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist

I have a `JList` with very long item names that cause the horizontal scroll-bar to appear in scroll-pane.

Is there anyway that I can word wrap so that the whole whole item name appears in 2 rows yet can be selected in one click?  I.E it should still *behave* as a single item but be *displayed* in two rows.

---

Here is what I did after seeing the example below

I added a new class to my project MyCellRenderer and then I went added `MyList.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer(80));` in the post creation code of my List. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: I seem to recall someone (was it Andrew) using a JLabel, HTML and simple style sheets to solve something like this.

Comment: Yes, of course, it was Andrew: [is-there-some-word-wrap-property-of-jlabel-exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861724/is-there-some-word-wrap-property-of-jlabel-exist/7861833#7861833). I do believe that this concept can also be used in your custom cell renderer.

Comment: Another alternative (why is everybody looking at me funny?) is to use a tool-tip for the long name and "Value is..." for the label itself.  Of course this would not work very well with the one concrete example given in HFoEs answer.  I would hate to have to mouse-over the list to distinguish between every guy called "Mohamed".

Answer (score 20):

Yep, using Andrew's code, I came up with something like this:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JListLimitWidth {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String[] names = { "John Smith", "engelbert humperdinck",
            "john jacob jingleheimer schmidt" };
      MyCellRenderer cellRenderer = new MyCellRenderer(80);
      JList list = new JList(names);
      list.setCellRenderer(cellRenderer);
      JScrollPane sPane = new JScrollPane(list);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(sPane);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);

   }
}

class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
   public static final String HTML_1 = "<html><body style='width: ";
   public static final String HTML_2 = "px'>";
   public static final String HTML_3 = "</html>";
   private int width;

   public MyCellRenderer(int width) {
      this.width = width;
   }

   @Override
   public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
         int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
      String text = HTML_1 + String.valueOf(width) + HTML_2 + value.toString()
            + HTML_3;
      return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, text, index, isSelected,
            cellHasFocus);
   }

}
```

Comment: It wasn't my smarts that did this but this one here: [Andrew's post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861724/is-there-some-word-wrap-property-of-jlabel-exist/7861833#7861833). I can't upvote his answer more than once, but I encourage anyone who thinks that my answer was helpful to upvote the link.

Comment: (as you all know, including @Andrew Thompson, I dont like html tricksing overly much, especially not if mis-used for hard-coded sizing <g>) so, why not use the actual with of the list instead of the fixed?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example!! I really appreciate it!!

Comment: Hey @HovercraftFullOfEels I just tried this code ... it doesnt seem to work for me.... I am not developing anything on browser it is a pure java appication and it doesnot wrap the text ... could you help me out. Here is what I did I added a new class to my project MyCellRenderer and then I went added MyList.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer(80)); in the post creation code of my List. Is there anything else I need to do? Thanks for you help and paitence

Answer (score -1):

You can also compute dynamically the width (instead of a fixed value):

```
String text = HTML_1 + String.valueOf(**list.getWidth()**) + HTML_2 + value.toString() + HTML_3;
```

So if the panel resizes the list, wrapping remains correct.

**Update**

And the result looks like this:
[image]

Comment: This does not work. If the JList is resized the height of the row will not be adjusted and funny visual things happen. See my attached image... I added green and red to help illustrate.

Answer (score -1):

It can be done even easier. You can create JList by consatructor with ListModel. In CustomListModel extends AbstractListModel, getElementAt() method can returns String with same html-formatted text. So this way do the same without cell renderer modification.

Comment: Wrapping is UI and not model related. Changing the model to accommodate the UI is bad.