# JLabel with HTML does not set width properly

Tags: java, html, swing, resize, jlabel

I am trying to set the width of a JLabel using an HTML div tag.

Consider the following code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Xyzzy extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Xyzzy frame = new Xyzzy();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

                String s = "x ";
                for (int i=0; i<200; ++i)
                    s += "x ";

                JLabel jl = new JLabel("<html><div style=\"width: 300px;\">" + s + "</div></html>");

                frame.add(jl);

                frame.setSize(600, 600);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I would have expected the JLabel to be 300 pixels wide, but in reality it is about 390 pixels wide. If I change the width specification to 200px, the resulting label is about 260 pixels wide.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know if it's always true, but in your case the size is always 30% bigger than the given width, try using `float size= 300 /1.3f;
                JLabel jl = new JLabel("<html><div style=\"width:"+size+"px;\">" + s + "</div></html>");` And the size will be of 300px. It's a wired workaround and I'm not sure it always work so I just put it in comment.

Answer (score 5):

This html code is too complicated for JLabel (support only part of HTML specification)
http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JLabel.html
Size of components depends on Layout.
I prefer MigLayout http://www.miglayout.com [simple tutorial](http://www.java-tutorial.ch/framework/miglayout-tutorial)

Edit: HTML in JLabel is very outdated

Comment: If HTML in JLabel is outdated, how do I make the text wrap? According to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861724/is-there-some-word-wrap-property-of-jlabel-exist), HTML is the way to go.

Comment: @ClausTøndering No HTML in JLabel is not outdated, it's the article and some of the description that are old and incorrect now.

Answer (score 3):

You're setting the width of the text in the HTML, not the width of the `JLabel`.

Use the `setPreferredSize` method to set the width of the `JLabel`.

```
frame.pack();

Dimension d = label.getSize();
d.width = width;
label.setPreferredSize(d);
```

Although it's better to let the `JLabel` size itself to allow the text to fit, as you've seen.

Comment: get/setPreferredSize does not work properly with the layout I'm using. Also, I still need the <html>...</html> tags in order to force the text in the JLabel to wrap.

Comment: @Claus Tøndering: You have to get the frame to lay out before you can use the sizes.  I fixed an error in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Gilbert, I add your code and end up with this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Xyzzy extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Xyzzy frame = new Xyzzy();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

                String s = "x ";
                for (int i=0; i<200; ++i)
                    s += "x ";

                JLabel jl = new JLabel("<html>" + s + "</html>");

                frame.add(jl);
                frame.pack();

                Dimension d = jl.getSize();
                d.width = 200;
                jl.setPreferredSize(d);

                frame.setSize(600, 600);

                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This simply does not work. I've also tried removing the HTML tags and the frame.setSize(600,600), neither of which produces what I'm looking for: A JLabel that is 200 pixels wide and has adjusted its height.