# Height of JLabel to grow with number of lines

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, multiline

I want my `JLabel` to be the height required for the particular string that is assigned to the text.  The text string can can have any number of lines, which use the `\n` in the string.  So if you have a string the `"Hello\nit\nis\nme\n"` the height of the label will automatically be adjusted to fit the 4 lines.

How to achieve that?

Comment: You might want to say it a 3rd time. :) Myself I'd use a JTextArea configured to look like a JLabel.

Answer (score 2):

- Use proper [JTextComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) rather than use HTML formatted text in the `JLabel`
- I think that for `"Hello\nit\nis\nme\n"` should be disabled [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) right `JComponent`

Answer (score 2):

A `JLabel`<sup>1</sup> would typically ignore the new-line character.  To get multi-line text, either use a mutli-line component such as a `JTextArea`<sup>2</sup> or use HTML formatting in the label.

[image]

1. Here is an [example of using HTML formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7861833/418556) (screenshot above).  The example uses styles (CSS) to cause the line breaks to be inserted automatically.  This is much easier than calculating where to insert line-breaks in text blocks manually.
2. Of course, a `JTextArea` having methods like [`setLineWrap(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setLineWrap%28boolean%29) & [`setWrapStyleWord(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setWrapStyleWord%28boolean%29) also handles line wrap automatically.