# How to add multiple Strings to JLabel without creating a new object

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, foreground

How can I add multiple Strings in JLabel without create a new Object with mouseListener  and I want it to display the list of Strinsg in block but it always display inline.

My question is everytime I have an String I need to create a new object of JLabel?
BTW I have a database with a lot of names and creating a lot of JLabel will be hard.

HERE is the image
[Click HERE](http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/7782/rodzf.jpg)

HERE is my current code with objects
I have a database that gets the String of names and then add to JPanel.

```
 x = new JLabel("name1");
      x1 = new JLabel("name2");
     x.setFont(new Font("calibri",Font.BOLD,20));
    x.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {         
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) { 
            x.setForeground(Color.blue);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            x.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            x.setForeground(Color.RED);             
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent a) {
            x.setForeground(Color.blue);

        }});
    add(x);
    add(x1);
```

Comment: look at JList, OR set the JLabel to html, and append <br/>+your new name

Comment: can you get all names first, and concat them with linebreak, set to one jlabel?

Comment: but when I click them with mouselistener I should get a different name.

Comment: *"but when I click them with mouselistener I should get a different name."* unless you want to spent a a lot of time fumbling around with font metrics and line breaks, I'd recommend using either a JList or JTable instead, the will do everything you want and lot more simply

Comment: I am using JList now HOw can I disable the blue box when I clicked the list of Strings?

Comment: @Poldz Kerk override key in UIManager, [search here](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are looking for a better control. What about JList?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Comment: I am using JList now HOw can I disable the blue box when I clicked the list of Strings?

Comment: Set a `ListCellRenderer` that ignores the selection.  However that seems a bad idea.  The user would **expect** a change to the selected list item.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML formatting inside Swing buttons, menu buttons, labels, etc.  Just use an html tag when you're setting the text.

Comment: See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861724/is-there-some-word-wrap-property-of-jlabel-exist/7861833#7861833) for instance.