# How to automatically break the text of a JLabel with ... when it gets too long with MigLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, miglayout

For example, have a `JLabel` normally show its text when the text is short enough:

> Hello world!

But automatically break it with "..." when it gets too long:

> Hello ladies and gent...

Is there any way to do this when you use MigLayout? In other layouts this is the default behavior but appearantly not in MigLayout...

[image]

Comment: I think that ***is*** the default behavior.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry, just discovered it was because I used MigLayout. Yes, with other layouts it does this just fine. With MigLayout it doesn't for some reason.

Comment: I've never used `MigLayout`, but I am *pretty* sure it has layout constraints when adding a GUI element that suggest/support a maximum size for it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Nope :( Look at the screenshot

Comment: Showing me a screen-shot of the text not going to `...` in no way convinces me that `MigLayout` does not have that ability.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Oh, ok. But apparently it needs to be enabled some way...

Comment: Surely [`width`](http://migcalendar.com/miglayout/javadoc/net/miginfocom/layout/LC.html#width%28java.lang.String%29) is the important thing here?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Didn't work for me.

Comment: I suggest you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure that I understand what you mean by "break": I'm assuming you want the ellipses to show up (to indicate that the label is longer) vs. simply cutting the text off.

- the ellipses are showing when the label's size is smaller than the text requires
- the label's minSize is about the same as its preferred
- by default, MigLayout doesn't size a component below its min

So you have to explicitly allow the manager to size smaller than the min by overruling the component's min with a component constraint:

```
content.add(new JLabel("we are looooong and getting longer by the minute"), "wmin 0");
```

(might be possible on a column constraint as well, didn't check)

Answer (score 1):

Place it inside `<html>` tags and use `<br />` to add new line

```
Mylabel.setText("<html><div style=\"text-align: center;\">"+
                    "First Line <br />"+
                    "Second Line</html>"
                );
```

This would look like

```
                 ----------------------
                 |    First Line      |
                 |    Second Line     | 
                 ----------------------
```

Comment: Nope.  I thought that from glancing at the title, but that is *not* what the OP wants.  Also, don't use `<br />` when there is [CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7861833/418556) to do the job better.