# Resize dialog message (JOptionPane) for long sentence with fixed width

Tags: java, swing, resize, joptionpane, jtextpane

I'm trying to resize the height of the dialog box (`JOptionPane`) for long sentence with hyperlink.

My code is ..

```
public class DialogTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JTextPane jtp = new JTextPane();
    Document doc = jtp.getDocument();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), " Hello Java World ", new SimpleAttributeSet());
        if ((3 == i) || (7 == i) || (15 == i)) {
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), " Hello Java World ", new SimpleAttributeSet());
            SimpleAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setUnderline(attrs, true);
            StyleConstants.setForeground(attrs, Color.BLUE);
            String text = "www.google.com";
            URL url = new URL("http://" + text);
            attrs.addAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF, url.toString());
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), text, attrs);
        }
    }
    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(jtp);
    jsp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(480, 150));
    jsp.setBorder(null);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jsp, "Title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}}
```

If I don't set the preferred size, that dialog is gonna be really long, and it's not readable. So, I want to fix the width to 480.

And, I want to adjust height depends on the length of the text.

If I run this code, I see the vertical scrollbar. But I don't want to show that scrollbar and adjust the height of the dialog.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Comment: um.. I didn't find the answer for me in the thread.

Comment: The gist of it is that you should not be using `setPreferredSize` (it does not do what you think it would do).  Sorry for not suggesting an alternative approach but I am short on time at the moment.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example). 2) What is the document type, HTML?  If so, you can use the same technique seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7861833/418556)..  (but if you cannot get it to work, post a MCTaRE rather than uncompilable code snippets).

Comment: http://java-sl.com/tip_text_height_measuring.html

Comment: thanks everyone who spent time on my question, user1967800
 gave me the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix the width and adapt the height, I personally use this trick :
You fix an arbitrary height and the targeted width with setSize, and then get the expected height with getPreferredSize() :

```
jtp.setSize(new Dimension(480, 10));
jtp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(480, jtp.getPreferredSize().height));
```

The full code would be :

```
public class DialogTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JTextPane jtp = new JTextPane();
    Document doc = jtp.getDocument();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), " Hello Java World ", new SimpleAttributeSet());
        if ((3 == i) || (7 == i) || (15 == i)) {
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), " Hello Java World ", new SimpleAttributeSet());
            SimpleAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setUnderline(attrs, true);
            StyleConstants.setForeground(attrs, Color.BLUE);
            String text = "www.google.com";
            URL url = new URL("http://" + text);
            attrs.addAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF, url.toString());
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), text, attrs);
        }
    }
    //JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(jtp);
    //jsp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(480, 150));
    //jsp.setBorder(null);
    jtp.setSize(new Dimension(480, 10));
    jtp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(480, jtp.getPreferredSize().height));

    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jsp, "Title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jtp, "Title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}}
```

Comment: Thank you user1967800 this works perfectly for my dialog. I almost gave up on this issue. but you saved me.

Answer (score 0):

To resize your JOptionPane please use the overridden class displayed in below URL:-

[ModifiableJOptionPane](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ModifiableJOptionPane.htm)