# JTable variable height of cells and coloring Strings via HTML Tags

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextarea, jtextpane

I have a `JTable` with cells that have variable heights because of there Content. I accomplished this by using a `JTextArea` in my `TableCellRenderer`. I want to Color parts of the `String` in different colors. `JTextPane` supports HTML tags and text area doesn't but with text pane it is not possible to change the height of the cell.

Any idea how I can use variable cell heights and coloring of the string with `JTable`?

```
public class LineWrapCellRenderer extends JTextPane implements TableCellRenderer {

    int rowHeight = 0;  // current max row height for this scan
    final int paddingRight = 4;
    final int paddingLeft = 4;
    Border padding = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, paddingLeft, 5, paddingRight);


@Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable table,
            Object value,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus,
            int row,
            int column){

        setContentType("text/html");
        setText(setHTML((String) value));
        setSelectionColor(Color.BLUE);


        this.setBorder(padding);//Abstände der Zeilen

        //markieren fals selektiert
        if (isSelected){
            setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
//          setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
        }
        else
        {
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
//          setForeground(table.getForeground());
        }

        // current table column width in pixels
        int colWidth = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth() + table.getIntercellSpacing().width;

        // set the text area width (height doesn't matter here)
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(colWidth, 1);
        setSize(dim);

        // get the text area preferred height and add the row margin
        int height = getPreferredSize().height + table.getRowMargin();


        // ensure the row height fits the cell with most lines
        if (height != table.getRowHeight(row)) {
            table.setRowHeight(row, height);
        }

        return this;
    }
```

using this code with JTextPane has no effect on the cell height. using the same code with JTextArea the height is adjusted.

Comment: *"..but with JTextPane it is not possible to Change the height of the cell."*  Isn't it?  Is the HTML specifying a body width using CSS?

Comment: @AndrewThompson _width_ and _height_ are not the same.

Comment: @icza  Well duh..  Nobody said they were.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7861833/418556) for how setting a *width* causes the component to have the desired *height.*

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 2):

You can set/change the height of each individual row with the following method:

[`JTable.setRowHeight(int row, int rowHeight);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowHeight-int-int-)

As for coloring parts of the text displayed in a cell, you can simply use HTML code, e.g.

```
String value = "<html>Following word is <font color=\"red\">RED</font>.</html>";
```

The default table cell renderer ([`DefaultTableCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html)) uses/extends `JLabel` which properly handles/accepts HTML code.

### Manual height

See this example:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");

JTable t = new JTable();
((DefaultTableModel)t.getModel()).setDataVector(new Object[][]{
        {"<html>Next word is <font color=\"red\">RED</font>.</html>", "50px"},
        {"<html>Following  is <font color=\"blue\">BLUE</font>.<br><br>"
            + "Long lines are automatically wrapped"
            + " as this long line demonstrates it.</html>", "150px"},
}, new Object[]{"Formatted text","Height"});
t.setRowHeight(0, 50);
t.setRowHeight(1, 150);
f.add(new JScrollPane(t));

f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
```

Result:

[image]

### Packing / Authoheight

If you want to "pack" all your rows to have the minimum height the value requires, you can do it like this:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");

JTable t = new JTable();
((DefaultTableModel) t.getModel()).setDataVector(new Object[][] {
        {"<html>Next word is <font color='red'>RED</font>.</html>", "50px" },
        {"<html><body style='width:200px'>Following  is"
            + " <font color='blue'>BLUE</font>.<br><br>"
            + "Long lines are automatically wrapped "
            + "as this long line demonstrates it.</body></html>", "150px" }, },
        new Object[] {"Formatted text", "Height"});

for (int i = 0; i < t.getRowCount(); i++)
    t.setRowHeight(i, t.getCellRenderer(i, 0)
        .getTableCellRendererComponent(t, t.getValueAt(i, 0), false, false, i, 0)
            .getPreferredSize().height);

f.add(new JScrollPane(t));

f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
```

Basically iterate over the rows, and ask the preferred height from the renderer, and set that as the row height.

**Note:** This required to set `width` style in HTML values that are auto-wrapped to multiple lines. If you don't do this, the preferred height of an HTML value will be the preferred height without auto-wrapping long lines (manual wrapping like `<br>` tags will still be considered).

This will result in this:

[image]

Comment: using setRowHeight with JTextPane has no effect. it makes them so small that you can´t see any Content which is very weird.

Comment: @lolung Added an example with image to show `setRowHeight()` works, also included coloring.

Comment: weird. tried to extend `DefaultTableCellRenderer` and set the height like in my code while Rendering but `getPreferredSize().height` is returning always the same height.

Comment: @lolung You shouldn't change row height from the renderer. Edited the answer to show how to "pack" the table to set the heights.

Comment: iterating the cells is working fine. My table can get very large and iterating can take very Long. any other idea?