# JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog dynamic size

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog`. It has to display a very long string. They length varies. So what I did was create a textArea, add the string to text area.  I don't want to do `setColumns`, `setRows`.

Is there a way dynamically adjust the size?  Do advice . Thanks!

```
String longString="asdas";//Long string. 
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(longString);
/*want to avoid setting the size*/
//textArea.setColumns(70);
// textArea.setRows(5);
textArea.setLineWrap( true );
textArea.setBackground(null);
textArea.setFont(null);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord( true );

int l_iResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( this, textArea , "Confirm Delete", 
                                                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION );
```

Comment: create your own message window lolz :D which is customizeable

Comment: *"I don't want to do `setColumns`, `setRows`"* Why not? BTW - consider using a `JLabel` with HTML formatting and setting a width to the `body` it will be as wide as specified, but only as tall as needed. Here is [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861724/is-there-a-word-wrap-property-for-jlabel/7861833#7861833)..

Comment: If i set  300 columns, 100 rows, then  i will have a big box, with small text and lot of empty space

Answer (score 1):

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(longString);
textArea.setSize( new Dimension(200, 16) );
```

Looks like if you specify a width around 200 (or greater) the text area will be able to calculate its height allowing for the wrapping of the text.

Comment: @Jacel, Define long? it worked for me using JDK8 on Windows 7. I copied the text from your first paragraph (twice) and It wrapped the text onto 13 lines.

Comment: You may need to do: textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300)); which for me makes a pretty darn big dialog :)

Comment: Yes,, textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300)); is a solution, but if you have small text..just length:10, then u have a small text in a humongous empty box.

Comment: @DevilsHnd, Nowhere did I suggest to use setPreferredSize, you should not be doing that. Each component is responsible for determining it own preferred size. My solution is to give a suggestion by setting the size, then the text area will determine its own preferred size based on the specified width. Don't clutter the answer with your own guess because now the OP is ignoring my working solution and hasn't responded to my further question. Post your own answer.