# How to wrap text in a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, text, jlabel, word-wrap

I have JLabel that displays a dynamic text. This text can be very long or short. I want to wrap text and I'm trying it this way:

```
    panel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 150));
    ....
    lblInfo=new JLabel();
    lblInfo.setText("<html><b>Q: "+ infoObj.getText()+"</b></html>");
    ...
    panel1.add(lblInfo);
```

But this doesn't seem to work. When a long text comes, this JLabel just goes out of the screen (beyond the size of my panel) and I can only see the end of it.

I found some solutions on Stack Overflow using JTextField instead of label. But due to some requirements in my project, I have to use JLabel itself in my case.

Comment: It is necessary to suggest a width as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7861833/418556).

Answer (score 3):

> When a long text comes, this JLabel just goes out of the screen

Yes, the text will only wrap when you have a `<br>` in the actual text. The `<br>` at the start of the text does nothing.

> I found some solutions on stackoverflow using JTextField instead of label

I doubt that. A `JTextField` ALWAYS displays text on a single line.

The suggestion you will find in the forum is to use a `JTextArea` with wrapping:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

Comment: *"the text will only wrap when you have a `<br>` in the actual text. The `<br>` at the start of the text does nothing."* 1) The OP is using the mark-up for bold, not break. 2) Break is neither the only, nor the best, way to wrap HTML text. (A CSS width is better.)

Comment: @Andrew yes I made the text bold. If I'm to add <br> to wrap text in JLabel, I have to do it in between my dynamically obtained text. So what's the the other option? I tried setting the size of JLabel. But when the text is very long, it just overflows the size and does not wrap.

Comment: *"So what's the the other option?"* Setting the width of the body of the HTML using CSS. See an example linked from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14011645/418556).