# Vertical Align text in java not showing up right

Tags: java, html, css, swing

I am using the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861724/is-there-a-word-wrap-property-for-jlabel) question in order to word-wrap my `JLabel`'s text and the code I am using to do that is this:

`label.setText("<html style=\"vertical-align:middle;\">"+label.getText()+"</html>");`

But the label displays the text wrong. For example if the label's text was *"the big bad wolf"* what I see is this:

**`<html style="vertical-align:middle;">the big bad wolf</html>`**

Why is the label not accepting my style?
**UPDATE:** Here is an example of what I am trying to do:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
private String warpWithHtmlTags(String...strings) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<html>");
    sb.append("<div style = \"text-align: center;\">");

    for(String s : strings) {

        sb.append("<p>")
          .append(s)
          .append("</p>");
    }

    sb.append("</div></html>");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Test with :

```
  String text = warpWithHtmlTags("line one", "longer line two", "even longer line three");
  JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
```

Comment: This worked but I I don't understand how the `div` is accepting the given style when it is not contained within quotes. Should it not be like this:
`<div style = " text-align: center; " >`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Apparently it works both ways. I updated my answer.