# How to you justify/ center text in a showOptionDialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Simple question related to centering text in a JOptionPane.showOptionDialog;

I tried using the method for a regular JOptionPane using JLabels but that method did not work as the JOptionPane.showOptionDialog method overrides the input text.

```
JLabel warning = new JLabel()
int x = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(warning,"I want this text \n to be centered","Confirm",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,finishedOptions, finishedOptions[0]);
warning.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use HTML for the message body, for example:

```
String msg = "<html><center><b>I want this text</b></center><center>to be "
           + "<font color=blue>centered</font></center></html>";
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg, "Confirm", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
```

This message box above would look something like:

[image]

Comment: So I’m still learning Java, how is it that html is allowed to be used this way, if you know?

Comment: [Read this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html). :)

Comment: The [HTML width can be set using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7861833/418556) (ATM the HTML is just wide enough to display the text). Remove `</center><center>` for the same effect.